# Adding an SSL certificate to Chrome

Tags: ssl, https

I am adding a new certificate to Chrome by going to Settings/Advanced/Manage Certificates. That works fine. When I navigate to https://somelocalweb/apiendpoint first I have to select Advanced/Proceed, then I am presented with a list of certificates that does not have the one I just added. Am I doing something wrong while adding a certificate so it does not make into the list? Hope, someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you import the certificate as what exactly - because there are several options. Do you find it under *"Your certificates"*? And was it issued by the CA expected by the server?

Comment: I imported it as a pfx file.It is a self-sighed certificate. Although I dont know much about the whole thing.

Comment: This does not answer what I asked for in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webserver must be served with a private key and a certificate.

In the certificate under the **Subject Alternative Name** (SAN) field, your domain must be there before starting the webserver.

```
Subject Alternative Name

DNS Name=somelocalweb
```

> **Tip**:
>
> 1. For local usage of https, create an self-signed CA (Certificate Authority).
> 2. Then register it on your system
> 3. Generate local certificates (and private key) using the self-signed CA from **1.** as issuer, and add your domains in the SAN field.
> 4. Google on how to load the certificate and key on your webserver.

**NOTE: Chrome requires certificates generated with `Version V3`.**